# How can i select multiple values from drop down list in a rdl report

Tags: c#, .net, rdl

I need to show multiple values in a drop down list, and i also need to allow the customer to pick more than one option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Report Data -> Parameters -> Choose your parameter then configure it like such.

[image]

Once you do that you will have a multiple selection dropdown box like such

[image]